# Issue posting to Web API with PHP Curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I have an ASP.NET Web API service on my hosting account.   I use this to populate some items on a website that I administer for a group that I belong to that is running PHP.  Our group has some games and allows users to check them out.  To that end I have an API for requesting a game.

I can use Postman to make the request.  It returns 201 Created and then I can see the record in the database afterward.

I have to use cURL with PHP as file_get_contents is not available on the server. Here is my PHP code

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.myurl.com/API/Games';
//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

// Will dump all of the json array
//var_dump(json_decode($result, true)); 
$games = json_decode($result, true); 

    if($_POST["requested"] != "true")
    {
?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <br /><br />
            <p>Select a game from the drop down and enter your email address and name, then click the button to send the request to the librarian.</p>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="requested" id="requested" value="true" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-md-2" for="Email">Game:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <select name="GameId" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="">Make Selection</option>
<?php

            foreach($games as $key => $game)
            {
                echo '<option value="'.$game[GameId].'">'.$game[GameName].'</option>';
            }
?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-md-2" for="Email">Email Address:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <input type="email" name="Email" id="Email" class="form-control" required />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-md-2" for="Member">Name:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" name="Member" id="Member" class="form-control" required />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Request Game" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p style="height:100px;">&nbsp;</p>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
        $GameId = $_POST["GameId"];
        $Email = $_POST["Email"];
        $Member = $_POST["Member"];

        foreach($games as $key => $game)
        {
            if($GameID == $game[GameId])
            {
                $Game = $game[GameName];
            }
        }
        $data = array("Email"=>$Email,"GameID"=>$GameId);
        $headers = ['Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded','charset:utf-8'];
        $url = 'http://www.myurl.com/API/GameRequests'; 
        //  Initiate curl
        $ch = curl_init();
        // Will return the response, if false it print the response
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($data));
        // Set the url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        //Set header
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
        // Execute
        $result=curl_exec($ch);
        // Closing
        curl_close($ch);
        var_dump(json_decode($result, true));

        $msg = $Member.', '.$Email.' has requested '.$Game;

        // use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
        $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

        $headers = "From: webmaster@groupname.org";

        // send email
        mail("groupname.librariana@gmail.com","My subject",$msg,$headers);
        echo $Game;
    }
?>
```

While it works through Postman it does not work when I am doing so from cURL.

Comment: you have to manage cookie and session in your CURL

Comment: I am not using either one

Comment: find a CURL module from github and try it

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what are you seeing? What does your var_dump after POST say? Are you logging anything on the server to check what it's receiving?